# How can I find the missing integers in a unique and sequential list (one per line) in a unix terminal?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Suppose I have a file as follows (a sorted, unique list of integers, one per line):

```
1
3
4
5
8
9
10
```

I would like the following output (i.e. the missing integers in the list):

```
2
6
7
```

How can I accomplish this within a bash terminal (using awk or a similar solution, preferably a one-liner)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk '{for(i=p+1; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=$1}' file

2
6
7
```

**Explanation:**

- `{p = $1}`: Variable `p` contains value from previous record
- `{for ...}`: We loop from `p+1` to the current row's value (excluding current value) and print each value which is basically the missing values

Comment: Can you explain me this logic please.

Comment: Variable p contains value from previous record and we loop from p+1 to current row's value.

Comment: why this answer is not coming at the top instead of being the highest rated and accepted one ?

Comment: @GauravKansal: Click on `Oldest` or `Votes` sorting option on bottom right corner of the question

Comment: What if the sequence doesn't begin with 1, but rather begins with whatever the first value in the file is? the seq/grep answer below did work for my situation

Comment: When input doesn't start with `1` it prints `1` in output also.

Comment: A slight modification to treat the first line in a file differently: `NR == 1 { last_number = $1 } ; NR > 1 { for (i = last_number + 1; i < $1; i++) print i; last_number = $1 }`

Answer (score 8):

Using `seq` and `grep`:

```
seq $(head -n1 file) $(tail -n1 file) | grep -vwFf file -
```

`seq` creates the full sequence, `grep` removes the lines that exists in the file from it.

Comment: I didn't personally find the `-` necessary, is there a reason it's there?

Comment: It's not necessary, it means the standard input, which is also the default.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -nE 'say for $a+1 .. $_-1; $a=$_'
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling no external program (if filein contains the list of numbers):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read num; do
    while (( ++i<num )); do
        echo $i
    done
done <filein
```

Answer (score 1):

To adapt *[choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)*'s clever answer for my own use case, I needed my sequence to deal with zero-padded numbers.

The `-w` switch to `seq` is the magic here - it automatically pads the first number with the necessary number of zeroes to keep it aligned with the second number:

```
-w, --equal-width     equalize width by padding with leading zeroes
```

My integers go from 0 to 9999, so I used the following:

```
seq -w 0 9999 | grep -vwFf "file.txt"
```

...which finds the missing integers in a sequence from `0000` to `9999`. Or to put it back into the more universal solution in *choroba*'s answer:

```
seq -w $(head -n1 "file.txt") $(tail -n1 "file.txt") | grep -vwFf "file.txt"
```

I didn't personally find the `-` in his answer was necessary, but there may be usecases which make it so.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.Int; say @a.Set (^) @a.minmax.Set;'
```

Sample Input:

```
1
3
4
5
8
9
10
```

Sample Output:

```
Set(2 6 7)
```

I'm sure there's a Raku solution similar to @JJoao's clever Perl5 answer, but in thinking about this problem my mind naturally turned to `Set` operations.

The code above reads `lines` into the `@a` array, `map`ping each line so that elements in the `@a` array are `Int`s, not strings. In the second statement, `@a.Set` converts the array to a `Set` on the left-hand side of the `(^)` operator. Also in the second statement,  `@a.minmax.Set` converts the array to a second `Set`, on the right-hand side of the `(^)` operator, but this time because the `minmax` operator is used, all `Int` elements from the `min` to `max` are included. Finally, the `(^)` symbol is the symmetric set-difference (infix) operator, which finds the difference.

To get an unordered whitespace-separated list of missing integers, replace the above `say` with `put`. To get a sequentially-ordered list of missing integers, add the explicit `sort` below:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.Int; .put for (@a.Set (^) @a.minmax.Set).sort.map: *.key;' file
2
6
7
```

The advantage of all Raku code above is that finding "missing integers" doesn't require a "sequential list" as input, nor is the input required to be unique. So hopefully this code will be useful for a wide variety of problems in addition to the explicit problem stated in the Question.

OTOH, Raku is a Perl-family language, so TMTOWTDI. Below, a `@a.minmax` array is created, and `grep`ped so that `none` of the elements of `@a` are returned (`none` junction):

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.Int;  .put for @a.minmax.grep: none @a;'  file
2
6
7
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/setbagmix
https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction
https://raku.org

Comment: First time learning about `raku` ++

Comment: @anubhava _"Raku (formerly known as Perl 6) is a sister language, part of the Perl family, not intended as a replacement for Perl, but as its own thing - libraries exist to allow you to call Perl code from Raku programs and vice versa."_ quote from: https://www.perl.org/