# Print the missing number in a unique sequential list with an arbitrary starting range or starting from 1

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sequential-number

This question is similar to [How can I find the missing integers in a unique and sequential list (one per line) in a unix terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491676/how-can-i-find-the-missing-integers-in-a-unique-and-sequential-list-one-per-lin/38491709#38491709).

The difference being is that I want to know if it is possible to specify a starting range to the list

I have noted the following provided solutions:

`awk '{for(i=p+1; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=$1}' file1`

and

`perl -nE 'say for $a+1 .. $_-1; $a=$_'`

file1 is as below:

```
5
6
7
8
15
16
17
20
```

Running both solutions, it gives the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
```

Note that the output start printing from 1.

Question is how to pass an arbitrary starting/minimum to start with and if nothing is provided, assume the number 1 as the starting/minimum number?

```
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
```

Yes, sometimes you will want the starting number to be 1 but sometimes you will want the starting number as the least number from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight variations of those one-liners to include a start point:

#### awk

```sh
# Optionally include start=NN before the first filename
$ awk 'BEGIN { start= 1 }
       $1 < start { next }
       $1 == start { p = start }
       { for (i = p + 1; i < $1; i++) print i; p = $1}' start=5 file1
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
$ awk 'BEGIN { start= 1 }
       $1 < start { next }
       $1 == start { p = start }
       { for (i = p + 1; i < $1; i++) print i; p = $1}' file1
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
```

#### perl

```sh
# Optionally include -start=NN before the first file and after the --
$ perl -snE 'BEGIN { $start //= 1 }
             if ($_ < $start) { next }
             if ($_ == $start) { $a = $start }
             say for $a+1 .. $_-1; $a=$_' -- -start=5 file1
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
$ perl -snE 'BEGIN { $start //= 1 }
             if ($_ < $start) { next }
             if ($_ == $start) { $a = $start }
             say for $a+1 .. $_-1; $a=$_' -- file1
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
```

Comment: thanks shawn, love this indentation, amazing how fellas here can write these complex scenarios, here's a thought, is it possible to sort of column print the existing number and the missing number as a columnar output of some sort, i suppose using diff can do that

Answer (score 2):

You can use your `awk` script, slightly modified, and pass it an initial `p` value with the `-v` option:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{p=p<1?1:p} {for(i=p; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=p<=$1?$1+1:p}' file1
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
$ awk -v p=10 'BEGIN{p=p<1?1:p} {for(i=p; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=p<=$1?$1+1:p}' file1
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
```

The `BEGIN` block initializes `p` to 1 if it is not specified or set to 0 or a negative value. The loop starts at `p` instead of `p+1`, and the last block assigns `$1+1` to `p` (instead of `$1`), if and only if `p` is less or equal `$1`.

This assumes that the default (1) is the minimum starting number you would want. If you would like to start from 0 or even from a negative number just replace `BEGIN{p=p<1?1:p}` by `BEGIN{p=(p==""?1:p)}`:

```sh
$ awk -v p=-2 'BEGIN{p=(p==""?1:p)} {for(i=p; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=p<=$1?$1+1:p}' file1
-2
-1
0
1
...
```

Comment: thanks this works fine to what am looking. had also tried using p=${x} setting x as an exported variable and that works fine too ... any chance you can advise how to print the existing and missing number as a columnar output? Or do I just print $1?

For example

5
6
7
8      9
       10
       11
       12
       13
       14
15
16
17
       18
       19
20

Answer (score 1):

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a=lines.map: *.Int; .put for (@a.Set (^) @a.minmax.Set).sort.map: *.key;'
```

Sample Input:

```
5
6
7
8
15
16
17
20
```

Sample Output:

```
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
```

Here's an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. No, it doesn't address the OP's request for a user-definable starting point. Instead the code above is a general solution that computes the input's `min`imum `Int` and counts up from there, returning any missing `Int`s found up--to the input's `max`imum `Int`.

Really need a user-defined lower limit? Try the following code, which allows you to set a `$init` variable:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a=lines.map: *.Int; my $init = 1; .put for (@a.Set (^) ($init..@a.max).Set).sort.map: *.key;' 
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
```

For explanation and shorter code (including single-line return and/or return without sort), see the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72221301/7270649
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

not as elegant as i hoped :

```
< file | mawk '
         BEGIN {    _= int(_)^(\
               ( ORS = "")<_) 
         }  { ___[ __= $0 ] }
         END { 
            do { 
                print _ in ___ \
                      ? "" : _ "\n" 
            } while(++_ < __) }' \_=10          
10
11
12
13
14
18
19
```